# Selecting and backspacing a tag just merges its text with that of the tag before it

Tags: bug, tags, keyboard

This is something I found across all S.E. communities.

Whenever I add a tag, and if I find out that the tag doesn't exist on the community yet, deleting this tag is a bit annoying.

See in the following screen capture what happens: when I select the tag to erase it, then press the <kbd>⌫</kbd> key on my computer, it doesn't delete the tag but instead keeps it and combines its text with the previously entered, validated tag without removing any characters from either of them.

So I have to forward delete at this point, and press <kbd>Space</kbd> to re-validate the previously entered tag.

I assume that <kbd>BkSp</kbd>/<kbd>⌫</kbd> should delete what is selected, and not mess with the previous tag that was validated.

[image: Screen capture]

Mac OS X 10.10, Safari 8.0.8

Comment: What platform is this on? Delete key works normally for me...

Comment: @Shog9: But does backspace? (That's actually the en-US name of the key being pressed.)

Comment: Yes, backspace works fine too. Can you reproduce this, @Nathan? The only way I can get close is by letting a tag pretty-render and then selecting *that* - which doesn't work, but also doesn't really behave at all like what's shown here.

Comment: @Shog9: Yep. Win 8.1x86, Pale Moon 25.7.2 (Firefox fork). It's been doing this for a while now to be honest. The GIF captures the exact sequence quite well.

Comment: Ok; I'm testing in Chrome 47 and Firefox 41 (also on Windows 8.1) Would be interested to know where else this is/isn't showing up.

Comment: @Shog9 for me it's there across S.E. communities

Comment: I'm reproducing this using Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7.

Comment: Both IE9 and the various unofficial forks of Firefox are not fully supported by SE. Not sure it is really browser related, but good chance it is.

Comment: I edited the question, this is Safari

Comment: I can reproduce this on Mac using Firefox and Chrome, so I'd say this is browser-independent. And I just wrote a lengthy post with screenshot and all jsut to notice you've been there before and done an even better job of visually communicating the issue at hand.

Comment: FWIW: I've noticed that selecting the tag right-to-left exhibits this behavior; selecting it left-to-right does not.